# Getting individual estimates from sklearn RandomForestRegressor?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-forest

What is the most appropriate way to get the individual tree predictions from an `sklearn` `RandomForestRegressor`?

I had implemented a subclass that manually called predict on each estimator and averaged the results.  While this works most of the time, it subverts the validation and parallelization of the actual forest predict method.
It also doesn't seem to work with the `pandas` output.
[scikit *learn*'s Introducing the set_output API](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/miscellaneous/plot_set_output.html)
The decision trees are fitted without labels, so if a `DataFrame` is passed in on predict, the forest complains.

It's been a while since the latest related question. Is there a better way?

```
class RFRegressor(RandomForestRegressor):
    """
    Random forest model.
    """
    def predict(self, X):
        self.estimators_y = np.array([e.predict(X) for e in self.estimators_])
        self.estimators_std = np.std(self.estimators_y , axis=0)

        return np.average(self.estimators_y, axis=0)

    def clearCache(self):
        delattr(self, 'estimators_y')
        delattr(self, 'estimators_std')
```

Other posts have suggest using the apply method to get leaf indices, extracting tree values, and averaging them. This snippet works (I think) but is horribly slow. `Numpy` is not my forte, so I'm sure it could be made more efficient.

```
values = [[np.average(rfr.estimators_[i].tree_.value[leaf], axis=1) 
           for i, leaf in enumerate(sample)] 
          for sample in rfr.apply(X)]
avg = np.average(values, axis=1)
```

Comment: I don't get what you are trying to do. Why to you want to fit individual estimator results? The only thing you do with it, is averaging the results. Which is exactly what the original `predict` does. Note that timing wise, there isn't much difference (between original predict, and predict on all estimators). At least on my machine. And obviously the original predict doesn't run in parallel, on several core, on my machine neither.  Is it to compute `std`? If so, aren't you rather looking for random forest quantile regressor?

Comment: Because computing std deviation of individual trees is not really a good estimation of error.

Comment: @chrslg Overriding the predict method is primarily to cache the estimator values into an attribute that can be accessed elsewhere after the predict call.  The std is just a convenience.
The _forest predict method does more than what I've implemented here, so I'd rather not override it and find a better way to get the estimator values.